# Dynamic column as a criterion in sumif function

Tags: excel, vba

Basically, i am trying to use sumif function in vba. Instead of using fixed rows and columns, i am trying to make everything dynamic. here is the code i wrote to accomplish the task but failed.

```
sh.Range("V" & StartRowData + j).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf _
                                    (MettBeheer.Range("A1", "A" & LastRowMettBeheer), sh.Range("A" & StartRowData + j).Value, MettBeheer.Range("K1", "K" & LastRowMettBeheer))
```

the first two parameter of the function are ok. this part of the code `Range("K1", "K" & LastRowMettBeheer)` where i want to make it dynamic. instead of a fixed k range, it could be from a to end of the used columns in the sheet based on the criteria give from this code `sh.Range("A" & StartRowData + j).Value`
any suggestion or help is highly appreciated?

Comment: Unclear what the 3rd parameter actually should be. You can use `Cells` though with a particular column number, instead of a hard-coded `K`.

Comment: the third parameter is where sum of the values is extracted from. i tried cells but failed. would be please make more clear to me. can you may be write me the codes that you are proposing.

Comment: What column do you want to use? What column number is it?

Comment: As you can see from above, it show start from row 1, to end of the row, however the column could be A,B,C...... depending on the input from another sheet.

Comment: I'm guessing you want to use `Application.Match` to find the correct column, given the value in `sh.Range("A" & StartRowData + j)`.

Comment: if you would elaborate it a bit more, i could try it.if you can provide me a sample code?